# This program sounds the bell!

Tags: c

I'm a brand-new student in programming arena so I can't grasp this program written in my book that I have been following for a few days. The program is like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"

main()
{
 printf("\a");
}
```

What does this program mean? Does this program mean that we could hear a ringing bell? I can't hear any ringing bell sound!!!

Comment: I'm fairly certain that won't work on win7, and that is platform dependant. I'd test but I didn't even connect my pc speaker this time around :)

Comment: I wonder what book that is, because this is not teaching you anything useful. Cute, perhaps... if it "works"... which it's not guaranteed to...

Comment: Blidi, lolz.. my platform is windows xp.

Polygenelubricants, I'm following "Teach yourself C (2nd ed) by Herbert Schildt.

Comment: You poor thing. Schildt books are generally regarded as the worse books around; they are full if technical errors and flat out false things. I suggest getting a [better book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) if you can.

Comment: "I'm fairly certain that won't work on win7" - so am I, but I wish to be either completely certain or find a way to do it. Can it be done?

Comment: Late, of course, but the bell **does sound on WIN7**. Just FYI.

Comment: Even later. On a Mac in Terminal, it plays the system error/alert sound.

Comment: [toot](http://github.com/vareille/toot) is a cross-platform C file and command line tool that try to call several sound generators to produce the beep

Comment: [Kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) is a great cross-platform terminal emulator that can play the terminal bell. You can configure the terminal emulator to enable terminal bells, and you can also configure the bell sound. You can even have the screen flash when the bell is triggered.

Answer (score 61):

ASCII character 7 is the BELL character, and it's represented in C as `\a`. Some terminals will produce a beep when this character is output on the terminal; nowadays, many don't. (I'm looking at you, Ubuntu.)

Comment: It would be either the **character is displayed** or **a bell is sounded**, but not both. For me, I just hear the bell, no character displayed.

Comment: In my case neither character is displayed nor beep is heared...but it was compliled correctly

Comment: With "displayed" I meant "sent to the terminal"; it wouldn't necessarily appear on the screen.

Comment: Is this why newer computers that come with Windows have built-in buzzers that can be used for nothing but beeping for error messages? Is that beep the computer makes from '\a' or something else?

Comment: For me, the screen flashes

Comment: I'm using Konsole on Ubuntu. By default it's showing a bell icon in tab title when I print "\a". For playing audio or showing notifs- from menu bar,`Settings > Configure Notifications`

Answer (score 37):

Back in the dark ages when [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) was codified out of the ashes of [BAUDOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code), a [terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASR-33_Teletype) was a large chunk of iron that hammered ink onto paper, often included a paper tape punch and reader, and interpreted keystrokes to generate an asynchronous serial signal at a few hundred baud with spinning wheels and relays.

In case an operator fell asleep to the soothing noises of it hammering out text, it had an actual bell it could ring. The character coded 007 in octal, 0x07 in hex, or as `\a` in a C character or string constant rang the bell when received.

As terminals became smaller and implemented with few or no moving parts, the physical bell was replaced by a beeper.

Exactly what your terminal emulator (aka a Console Window in Windows, xterm or something similar in Unix) does when it is asked to display that control character is not well standardized today. It ought to make a noise or flash the window, but your mileage will vary.

Comment: Nice explanation! It'd be cool to hook up a physical bell to a modern computer!

Comment: Indeed depends on the terminal. Proved on a Win10 HP210 machine when \a is output. It sounds the bell when using: cmd, git-bash (MinGW terminal), wsl -d Ubuntu20.04 bash (from cmd), wsl -d OpensuseLeap15.2 bash (from cmd). But no sound is hear on Mobaxterm (on same WSL Linux distributions as above or on its own CYGWIN_NT-10.0-WOW).

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at this wikipedia entry: [bell character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character):

*In the C Programming Language (created in 1972), the bell character can be placed in a string or character constant with \a ('a' stands for "alert" or "audible" and was chosen because \b was already used for backspace).*

Comment: Either speaker didn't beep in my case

Comment: it usually uses ancient PC speaker (i mean the thing that beeps really loud if BIOS fail to boot or an error when initializing BIOS) that come with some laptops or PC before UEFI exist

Answer (score 6):

`\a` does in fact trigger the system chime. It's the escape sequence for the ASCII `BEL` character.

Answer (score 5):

You'll hear a beep from your PC's internal speaker (not the external speakers or headphones you may have attached).

Comment: Either speaker didn't sounds beep in my windows xp

Comment: It will not necessarily be the PC speaker at all. It totally depends on the terminal, OS, system, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Strings can contain characters which are handled different from all the other characters. The most often explicit used one is `'\n'`. The `'\n'` character does not print a character in the console, instead it tells the console to start a new line. Such special characters are called non printable since they have no own visible representation in c and have to use escape sequences instead.

In the escape sequence `"\a"` the backslash before the a tells the compiler that the a is an identifier for a special character and will store its char-value instead of the char-value of `'a'`.

The `'\a'` escape sequence is the audible bell character, giving this character to a console via print() should cause a beep sound. Some consoles wont beep.

Here are [some](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/escape_sequences) special characters, the link is from a c++ reference but most should be valid for c.

Answer (score 3):

\a is the C representation of the ASCII audible alert ("bell") control character.
On an old-school serial terminal, outputting that character produced a "beep" sound. Your terminal emulator may or may not implement this feature.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from all the answers you've got, take into account that your program won't probably compile. Here is the fixed version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\a");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The most important change is that system headers must be surronded with < and >, instead of quotes. Also, it is better to know that the main() function always returns an int (to the operating system), and that this int is coded in two constants, EXIT_SUCCESS, and EXIT_FAILURE, in the header stdlib.h

Comment: Take into account the other answers. The BEL character may or may not ring the bell in your system. Change "printf("\a");" with " printf("Hello, world");"
If the message "Hello, world" appears on the screen, then your terminal does not support the BEL character.

Comment: I've tested the program as in the cource code above, and it works on Windows 7, using mingw' gcc.

Comment: @Baltasarq It's not just dependent upon Windows 7, but also upon the terminal you're using. I assume that by "it works on Windows 7" that you mean "it works on cmd.exe in Windows 7", but it might not, for instance, work on [Console 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).

Comment: Your code contains three changes, but only one of them is strictly necessary. "system headers must be surronded with < and >, instead of quotes" Include paths are implementation defined, and major compilers have no trouble finding system headers surrounded with quotes. It is considered good practice to use `<>` for system headers, but *must* sounds too strong. "the main() function always returns an int" Since C99, the implicit `int` rule is removed, so declaring the return type is mandatory, but the main function has a special rule that `0` is implicitly returned if control reaches the end.

Answer (score 2):

Try something simpler:

```
printf("hello\tworld");
printf("hello\nworld");
```

and see what happens.

Your example with the BELL char, as others have pointed out, probably won't work on today's toasters^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H computers; most terminals redirect the 'bell' character to either be discarded or to flash the terminal briefly.

And believe me, you want to keep it that way for the night-coding sessions :)

Answer (score 1):

The above program which you have written I have tried it in the code blocks using GNU GCC Compiler..

It was working fine..

If you want to hear a beep sound you can try it another way it will only be useful in Windows!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
main()
{
   Beep(600,600); /* you have to enter both the values whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of interest this appears to work in all builds that don't have a wWinMain or WinMain entry point. `wprintf(L"\a")` sounds fine for Unicode builds. (Win 7 here).

The PC speaker used to depend on "speaker.drv" but that little beauty has been taken away some time back and replaced with beep.sys which is now moved into the [user mode system sounds agent](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2010/01/04/whats-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7/).

Enabling and disabling the speaker from the command prompt is also discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/227939/how-to-make-the-pc-speaker-beep-from-the-windows-7-command-prompt).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int i = 263;
    putchar(i);  // or you can directly use putchar(263);
    return 0;
}
```

This program produces a bell sound while you are on the output screen

Answer (score 0):

the problem isnt about wheter your C program compiles its fully depend your terminal settings usually they make beeps using PC speakers that comes with laptop and PCs before UEFI exist

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker

i tested it using 2 laptops one of them were bought before UEFI even a thing and other bought after UEFI become common thing

i run `echo -e '\a'` on both test (both linux system with `pcspkr` module loaded) and sure the laptop before UEFI exist is beep other laptop just silent

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this response is a bit late. The bell character works for me using the Tera Term VT serial monitor running on Win10. I'm sending it from a Raspberry Pi Pico to audibly confirm some activity while probing its gpio pins.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).