# Is there any modern use for the bell character (\a)

Tags: java, ini

I had the idea to make an INI reading/writing library for my personal use, so I looked up the specification on Wikipedia. In the [Escape character section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Escape_characters), I found one called the "Bell character". After some googling, I found [this page](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-emit-a-beep-by-printing-the-ascii-bell-character-to-the-co.html) that gave an example of how to use it. I tried it out, but I didn't hear anything. After further googling, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456167/1275092) that specifically pointed out Ubuntu (what I'm using) as not making the sound. It also says that many other OS' don't support it.

So is there any reason to use it? Any at all?

Answer (score 1):

One modern use is that it's used in xterm escape sequences as a terminator.

```
ESC]0;stringBEL -- Set icon name and window title to string
ESC]1;stringBEL -- Set icon name to string
ESC]2;stringBEL -- Set window title to string
```

Above copied from: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title-3.html