# What happens when I call the ␇ character in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ascii, windows-server-2008-r2

Whilst attempting to answer the [Play a sound any sound question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18392/11159), I ran into the `␇` character.

However, when trying to call this in MATLAB, I noticed something strange: Nothing happened.

Using R2012b, I copied it from the browser into MATLAB.

Here are some observations:

1. When pasting the character, a red colored square is displayed
2. When hitting enter, no error was given.
3. Adding zero to it ␇ +0 also does nothing.
4. Using it in a string seems possible, but gives a strange result: '␇'+0 = 26
5. Calling it in a function does something strange, try `mean(␇)` and your command never seems to end (except with control+c)

To conclude, here is my main question:

### What happens when I run `␇` in Matlab, and why does MATLAB treat this apparently invalid input in such a strange way?

Comment: how did you even get that character? I tried pasting it from your question, into MATLAB 2012b on Windows, and I am unable to replicate anything you state, except the first and second point

Comment: I'm using Matlab 2013a on ubuntu and I get "Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB
statements or expressions."

Comment: I dont know what you expect, this is just another Unicode character outside the range of characters that the command prompt understands: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2407/index.htm. Why do expect it to play a sound at all?

Comment: @MZimmerman6 That is exactly what I did as well, strange that it results in different responses for you. Perhaps dependant on how the OS is setup?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin nevermind, I am able to replicate it in Matlab 2012b for Windows. After doing a bit of Googling, BEL is an ANSI character that was used to produce a tone when printed to command prompt. Some OS's no longer do this, but you can still replicate it on windows by opening a command prompt windows, pressing Ctrl+G, and hitting enter. You get that wonderful "bell" tone

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin here is another interesting SO question about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456138/this-program-sounds-the-bell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2407/index.htm) you entered is just another Unicode character outside the range that the MATLAB command prompt (and possibly even the editor) knows how to display. Just because it represents the *"symbol for bel"* doesn't mean it has any special significance or would play a sound when entered (no more than other [musical symbols](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/List_of_useful_symbols#Music) like: `♩` or )

Of course you can always have it saved in a regular string and display it in a GUI window:

```
% The default on Windows is 'windows-1252'
feature('DefaultCharacterSet','UTF-8')

c = char(9223);
uicontrol('style','text', 'units','normalized', 'position',[0 0 1 1], ...
    'string',['char = ' c], 'FontName','Arial Unicode MS', 'FontSize',72)
```

[image: bel_symbol]

or even get its encoding in say UTF-8:

```
>> cellstr(dec2hex(unicode2native(c,'UTF-8')))
ans = 
    'E2'
    '90'
    '87'
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863147/matlab-how-to-display-utf-8-encoded-text-read-from-file

Comment: I suppose that it was wishfull thinking that a sound might be played, and the incapability to change it under default settings is comprehensible. However, the difference in behavior between `clear, mean(a)` and `clear, mean(♩)` surprises me. Basically this could mean that if such a char ever appeared in your code, or was accidentally evaluated, it would never throw an error but just hang indefinitely. -- Do you suppose there is anything like `end` that could be entered to 'complete' `mean(♩)`, or would you say it is a bug?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: the issue here is that the **command window** (not the MATLAB engine) does not correctly handle input from the entire Unicode character set. As I have shown in the question I linked to, proper Unicode support is still lacking in the MATLAB IDE.. For instance MATLAB refuses to execute an M-file saved in UTF-8 encoding with [BOM marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), you'll have to work in an external editor to ensure proper encoding (at least that's the case on my Windows machine with the default en-US [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale)).

Comment: To understand what I mean: open [Microsoft Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29), create a simple script/function (something like `disp('hello world')`), go to "File > Save As..", choose "Unicode" encoding, and save the file as `hello.m`. Try to execute this script in MATLAB or even open it in the builtin editor and you'll see the problem... This basically saves the file in "UTF-16 LE" encoding, which MATLAB apparently does not understand (among other encodings).