# MatLab, missing ->> in command line

Tags: matlab

I use MATLAB R2012b, and for some reason occasionally when I put "bad stuff" in the command line, it executes, but then the --> arrow thing besides the $$f_x$$ symbol disappears and I can't do anything in the command line.

For instance if I write an if statement with nothing else, it erases that arrow thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're starting a loop. It's waiting for you to type the code to go within the loop, and it is terminated when you type `end` to end the loop. For example:

```
if(x==0)
  y = y + 1;
end
```

Comment: What I want to know is that what happens if i can't figure out what the error is?

Comment: So "end" is terminate in Matlab? I am very new to this sorry

Comment: `end` tells Matlab to end the loop.

Comment: What if that doesn't work?

Comment: You can press `Ctrl+C` to break out of any execution.

Comment: If nothing works, remeber you are the Boss! Go to taks manager and end the MATLAB process :D

Answer (score 1):

When you see this it typically means that you did not finish a command yet. This most commonly occurs with statements like `for` or `if`.

Example:

```
if 1
```

Now you are inside the if statement, and not simply at the basic prompt. Therefore you will not see anything happen. This can be tested by continuing with:

```
1+1 %Normally outputs 2
```

Obviously nothing happens. You now have two choices. Either you realize that the `if` was there by mistake, and you cancel with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. In this case you will not see any output. Of course you can also choose to finish the statement:

```
end
```

Comment: Obviously not happening, but perhaps interesting for other readers is that it can also happen when you provide invalid input characters, like `mean(␇)` as described in [What happens when I call the ␇ character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097072/what-happens-when-i-call-the-character-in-matlab)