# Strange error with C++ console app when running a for loop

Tags: c++

So I was messing around with the dimensions of an array, starting it with [25][25]. I've eventually found the best dimensions of it ([21][25]) but I've forgot to change the condition in the for loop which is displaying the array (Initially it was y<25 and it had to be y<21). The program ran just fine but there was a strange error. What the array was displaying was pretty strange and also it made sounds (the sound is very familiar, although I can't tell exactly what it is. I can guess it is the one you get when you try to open a shortcut which file's destination was deleted but I'm not very sure, as I've said very familiar tho.)[image] I have also uploaded a screenshot and you can see the error for yourself ( the 2 lines before the "Process returned 0" one). Any idea why these specific characters tho ( I mean a smiley face? come on.)?

Comment: A picture may be worth a thousand words, but posting the code would be better.

Comment: You're probably running off the end of a string and printing random garbage. But since you haven't shown any actual code (pictures of PART of the code are utterly useless), we can't help you.

Comment: Well, as I've said ( or forgot to mention): I've figured it out already but oh well. I'll edit it now and put in code too.

Comment: Its called undefined behavior.  Once you go out of bounds on the array all bets are off.

Comment: Ok I also get an error that says that my code is not formatted as proper code. I honestly don't even know what's going on anymore. I can't even paste it to one of my friends over Skype. It just simply doesn't send. I can't show the code

Comment: You are probably [listening the bell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456138/this-program-sounds-the-bell)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're trying to access unallocated memory locations by keeping your loop condition y<25 and hence getting the strange output. And please try to put in the code too when asking similar questions.

Comment: Yeah I've figured out what's going on. I just asked why the specific characters tho. I also get an error when trying to paste in the code. It says it's not properly formatted as code although it is since the compiler runs it (at least)

Comment: The characters are just garbage sitting at those locations, no telling what gets revealed ;)