# How can I change '\a' sound?

Tags: c++, operating-system, codeblocks

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    while(getch()!=27){
        cout << "\a\n";
        Sleep(500);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I heard I could change '\a' alert sound.
It's echoing sound now, but i wanna change it.
How can I?

More question : Is way to change the sound all different to each development environment?

P.S. I'm using Code::Blocks now

Comment: That is normally done by changing the "bell" sound in the terminal program you're using or in the operating system. I'm not aware of any way of doing it using character codes.

Comment: Maybe you can ... maybe even you can do it with a C (or C++) program ... but it's not straighforward. What happens when you `putchar('\a');` (or any variation thereof) is that the character gets ultimately sent to the OS and from the OS to the output device. It's the output device that choses to "represent" it as an audible sign.

Comment: This is completely dependent on your operating system, terminal, etc. C++ is just sending the control character to the terminal, which will do (or not do) whatever it wants. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456138/this-program-sounds-the-bell

Comment: Looks like Windows. You could use the [PlaySound function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)) instead.

Comment: You change it via your operating system settings.

Comment: So, in other words, tag your question with the operating system and terminal you are using, and then move this to SuperUser to find out how to change the bell on that OS/terminal; however, first check there whether the question was already asked/answered.

Comment: And could you guys explain me how to change-alert sound in order?

Comment: #6 I couldn't find the question was already asked and answered in google... could you find it for me?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's probably the "Default Beep" sound in your sound scheme, but whether it actually plays is a terminal setting.

Comment: I removed the tag C since this question only belongs to C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, you may use `Beep()` from `windows.h` as shown:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(void) {
    Beep(500, 500);

    return 0;
}
```

The relationship between the number and frequency is directly proportional, i.e.

- Less frequency (like `400, 400`) - less sound for 400 ms (0.4s)
- More frequency (like `1000, 1000`) - more sound for 1000 ms (1s)

**Edit:** There's no correct method to alter the bell sound. It's totally up to the opearting system. The only way you can use the `Beep()` to generate some different frequencies which do sound different than a normal beep produced by `\a` escape sequence.

Comment: Sorry I don't wanna use Beep function. Is there any way to change alert sound using '\a'?

Comment: @kbk0421 No, this is the best method you could've used. The `\a` is dependent upon the operating system. It'll sound different in Windows and different in Unix.

Comment: @kbk0421 I've updated the answer. Read the **Edit** part.

Comment: Okay, so you meant I can't change it in my development environment, huh? Thanks for answering to my question :)

Comment: @kbk0421 I don't know anything about your development environment and I can't exactly say how will you do that. But yeah, it's simply possible with `windows.h` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I found in Win10 enviroment for C++ command for **cout << "\a";** C++ reacts on changing sound in Win10 system enviroment. If you want to change sound or implement custom sound just **press right-click on the speaker icon in lower left corner of the taskbar -> than go into "Sounds" -> than from a list please change sound type named "critical stop".**