# Why use escape characters in C language

Tags: c

Why use escape characters when writing a C program?

I have been looking at this example program using the \a escape character which is shown in the bottom of the question.

What is the purpose of this as on the console the print out is the same without the \a escape characters?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("My mobile number "
          "is 7\a8\a7\a3\a9\a2\a3\a4\a0\a8\a");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: @SuperStormer Ah right ok, I see now although it doesn't make a sound on my PC but I get the point :). If you want to leave an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

That is audible bell, when running the program it should make a sound.
check out the link

[This program sounds the bell!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456138/this-program-sounds-the-bell/27453123)

Edit: Logically speaking it should make a sound every time it comes across \a,
it does not effect the string, like \\ which would added backslash.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of escape characters is to represents values that do not have a character representation.

The `\a` escape sequence is defined as :

```
\a (Audible bell) – A beep is generated indicating the execution of the program to alert the user
```

The use of it is probably historical as I don't think that sending that value to stdout will actually have the shell make your computer bleep.